# Handle compress command error messages on AIX

Tags: shell-script, aix, compression

I am working on production issue and unable to reproduce error message for compress command.

#### Current Solution

We have case-esac block in shell wrapper that handles messages as follows;

```
case "$MSG" in
    "This file is not changed; compression does not save space.")
            echo "$MSG"
            ;;
    *unchanged*)
            echo "$MSG"
            ;;
    *)
            echo ERROR
            ;;
esac
```

#### Problem Scenario

The compress command when called through wrapper (for some files) produces error message (let say, **Type 1**);

```
 -- file unchanged
```

However, executing the same command (for same set of files) on command line produces different error message (let say, **Type 2**);

```
This file is not changed; compression does not save space.
```

Can someone help me understand this behavior? If possible, suggest reproducing **Type 1** error message

Comment: I have not seen any reply yet, so posted the same question.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=a3bcd7ba-b9cd-46fd-85b1-0c966a4a204a#

Answer (score 0):

The "does not save space" message would probably be shown for cases where the program looks at the blocksize of the filesystem on which you are compressing, and realizes that the number of *blocks* in the resulting file is the same.  You can see similar behavior with the zip program.  By refusing to compress the file, the developer assumed they were improving performance.

More often, compress utilities simply check if the resulting file would be smaller (since the compression algorithm adds a table, which is overhead).

For example, the IBM manual page shows that compress has -f/-F options (see [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/compress.htm)) which *force* compression.

Finally, "already compressed" comes when the utility inspects the file and notices either the suffix or the fact that the file begins with the codes that indicate it is compressed.

Comment: Thomas, is there any particular reason that same command when executed two different ways as explained in the question, will result in two different results.

Comment: Is that for the same identical set of input files?  Perhaps not.  If you were redirecting the output of the script, then some programs detect that.  Otherwise, if the compress program runs short of memory, by processing several files on the same command-line, that could also give a difference (but less likely0.

Comment: Yes, for same identical set. I wonder why IBM AIX manual doesn't list that message.

Comment: Manuals typically do not list all of the messages, though they may give a summary of the different exit-codes.